# How do I replace （…） with （…More） when text is too long

Tags: ios, uilabel

I've create a UILabel.When the text is too long, I hope to use (.. more) to replace (...).I have already tried it,but I did not demand results.

```
UILabel * writtenContentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, ScreenWidth - 20 , 70)];
writtenContentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
writtenContentLabel.text = [str stringByAppendingString:@"More"];
writtenContentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
[self addSubview:writtenContentLabel];
```

How do I do？

Comment: ... is self explanatory  that there is more text . Why to add explicit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
- (NSString*)stringWithElipsisMore:(NSString*)oringinalStr withLabel:(UILabel*)label
{
    CGRect rect = label.frame;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];

    NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:label.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};
    const CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize stringSize = [oringinalStr boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        attributes:attributes
                                           context:nil].size;

    if (stringSize.height > rect.size.height) {
        float proportion = rect.size.height / stringSize.height;
        NSString *subStr = [oringinalStr substringToIndex:oringinalStr.length * proportion];

        CGSize stringSize = [subStr boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:attributes
                                                  context:nil].size;
        while (stringSize.height < rect.size.height) {
            subStr = [oringinalStr substringToIndex:subStr.length + 1];
            stringSize = [subStr boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                            attributes:attributes
                                               context:nil].size;
        }

        subStr = [subStr substringToIndex:subStr.length - 1];

        while (stringSize.height > rect.size.height){
            subStr = [subStr substringToIndex:subStr.length - 1];
            stringSize = [subStr boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                  attributes:attributes
                                                     context:nil].size;
        }

        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(subStr.length - 7, 7);
        NSString *subSubStr = [subStr stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"...more"];
        return subSubStr;
    } else {
        return oringinalStr;
    }
}


    NSString *subStr = [self stringWithElipsisMore:str withLabel:writtenContentLabel];
    writtenContentLabel.text = subStr;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a custom label view to achieve this.

Replace your `UILabels` with any of the following custom labels. Both of them support custom `truncationTokenString` method.

- `MDHTMLLabel` https://github.com/mattdonnelly/MDHTMLLabel ***(I recommend this control)***
- `TTTAtributtedLabel` https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

You can change the default ellipsis using,

`[label setTruncationTokenString:@"...More"];`

Comment: it's currently deprecated, but I cannot find documentation about what I'm supposed to use. Any advice?